# Paypal IPN not executing license creation code

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

Let’s get detailed…cause I’m stumped.

Server File structure:

```
/home/name/public_html/CryptlexApi.php
/home/name/public_html/generate-license.php see below
/home/name/public_html/generate-license-IPN_combined.php
/home/name/public_html/paypalIPN.php
```

[source](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/PaypalIPN.php)

generate-license.php:

```php
<?php
    require('CryptlexApi.php');

    // pass this secret as query param in the url e.g. https://yourserver.com/generate-license.php?cryptlex_secret=SOME_RANDOM_STRING
    $CRYPTLEX_SECRET = "SOME_RANDOM_STRING";

    // access token must have following permissions (scope): license:write, user:read, user:write
    $PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN = "Yes, I have my PAT here";

    // utility functions
    function IsNullOrEmptyString($str){
        return (!isset($str) || trim($str) === '');
    }

    function ForbiddenRequest() {
        http_response_code(403);
        $message['error'] = 'You are not authorized to perform this action!';
        echo json_encode($message);
    }

    function BadRequest($error) {
        http_response_code(400);
        $message['error'] = $error;
        echo json_encode($message);
    }

    function VerifySecret($secret) {
        if($secret == $GLOBALS['CRYPTLEX_SECRET']) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function parsePayPalPostData() {
        $postBody['company'] = $_POST['payer_email'];
        if(IsNullOrEmptyString($postBody['email'])) {
            $postBody['company'] = "";
        }

        $postBody['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
        if(IsNullOrEmptyString($postBody['quantity'])) {
            $postBody['quantity'] = NULL;
        }


        $postBody['email'] = $_POST['payer_email'];
        if(IsNullOrEmptyString($postBody['email'])) {
            BadRequest('email is missing!');
            return NULL;
        }

        $postBody['last_name'] = $_POST['last_name'];
        if(IsNullOrEmptyString($_POST['last_name'])) {
            BadRequest('last name is missing!');
            return NULL;
        }
        $postBody['first_name'] = $_POST['first_name'];
        if(IsNullOrEmptyString($_POST['first_name'])) {
            BadRequest('first name is missing!');
            return NULL;
        }

        $postBody['order_id'] = $_POST['txn_id'];
        if(IsNullOrEmptyString($postBody['order_id'])) {
            BadRequest('reference is missing!');
            return NULL;
        }
        return $postBody;
    }

    try {

        if(VerifySecret($_GET['cryptlex_secret']) == false) {
            return ForbiddenRequest();
        }

        CryptlexApi::SetAccessToken($GLOBALS['PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN']);

        $product_id = "this is my product id";

        $postBody = parsePayPalPostData();

        if($postBody == NULL) {
            echo "no data \n";
            return;
        }


        $email = $postBody['email'];
        $first_name = $postBody['first_name'];
        $last_name = $postBody['last_name'];
        $quantity = $postBody['quantity'];

        // required for renewing the license subscription
        $order_id = $postBody['order_id'];

        // creating user is optional
        $user_exists = false;
        $user = CryptlexApi::GetUser($email);
        if($user == NULL) {
            $user_body["email"] = $email;
            $user_body["firstName"] = $first_name;
            $user_body["lastName"] = $last_name;
            $user_body["company"] = $last_name;
            // generate a random 8 character password
            $user_body["password"] = substr(md5(uniqid()), 0, 8);
            $user_body["role"] = "user";
            $user = CryptlexApi::CreateUser($user_body);
        } else {
            $user_exists = true;
        }

        echo "Quantity = $quantity \n";
        // creating license
        if($quantity != NULL) {
            $license_body["allowedActivations"] = (int)$quantity;
        }
        $license_body["productId"] = $product_id;
        $license_body["userId"] = $user->id;
        $metadata["key"] = "order_id";
        $metadata["value"] = $order_id;
        $metadata["visible"] = false;
        $license_body["metadata"] = array($metadata);

        $license = CryptlexApi::CreateLicense($license_body);

        http_response_code(200);
        echo $license->key;

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        http_response_code(500);
        echo 'message: ' .$e->getMessage();
    }
```

Ok, So if I do the following in the terminal, I will successfully create a user/license

```
curl -d "payer_email=emailaddress%40gmail.com&quantity=1&last_name=smith&first_name=bob&txn_id=ordernumber" -X POST https://mywebsite.com/generate-license.php?cryptlex_secret=SOME_RANDOM_STRING
```

So, I take that code and put it in paypalIPN.php and renamed to generate-license-IPN_combined.php
In the paypalIPN.php file, I inserted the above code here:

```php
// Check if PayPal verifies the IPN data, and if so, return true.
if ($res == self::VALID) {
    ######## I put all of my code above right here #########
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

The IPN code seems to work since the Paypal IPN simulator says it does. Nothing happens on the database side though. I’ve removed checks and even went as far as putting this code before the IPN but it’s not working. Please help.

Comment: The simulator will tell you if it was able to deliver the IPN, it won't tell you if your code was able to post back the IPN and get a valid response. That is for you to determine.

Comment: Are you sure. The simulator  responds back with a successful or failed handshake. Handshake tells me that it received the valid response from my code.

Comment: The successful handshake is based on whether they received an HTTP 2xx response from posting the IPN. Validating an IPN is a separate step that involves your server posting the IPN back to PayPal.

Comment: Right, the code in PaypalIPN.php does that.
This code: https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/PaypalIPN.php

Comment: Sure, that's some code. Whether it is successfully validating particular IPNs on your server or not remains to be seen. That's what you'll need to add full logging for and debug.

Comment: The best code in the world isn't going to do anything if, for example, your server can't open an HTTPS connection back to `https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`

Comment: I think I see the confusion.  I thought the IPN simulator did more.  But, I see now that I need to use the "IPN sandbox testing" to actually test my backend processing.  At least that's how I read this here:https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/IPNTesting/
Now...to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to generate test IPNs in sandbox is to pay with a link of the form:

`https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_xclick&item_name=test&amount=100&currency_code=USD&business=sandboxbusinessemail@domain.com&notify_url={URL_ENCODE_YOUR_IPN_LISTENER_URL}`

(Reference: [HTML Variables for PayPal Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/) )

Get a sandbox business account to sub into the above, and a sandbox personal account to pay with, via: https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F

Review the business account's IPN history via: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history

Comment: First off, that is all very helpful, thank you.
Sadly, it still doesn't work. 
I set up a sandbox buyer/seller.  Made the sandbox button on my site and changed the sellers IPN to match mine.  

The transaction succeeds but my license isn't generated.


Can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The above isn't a fix, it's so you can generate test events and debug the problem. You need to fully instrument your code and log everything to find where and what the problem is.

Comment: Don't forget to call `useSandbox()` for the above sample you linked to.  You could make this be dynamic based on whether you receive an IPN with test_ipn=1 or not, but also make sure sandbox events don't actually generate and send licenses, but rather log things and do a "dry run" of your license creation process.

Comment: As you can probably tell, I'm no software engineer (and completely new to PHP) so I appreciate your patience.  I wasn't calling useSandbox() (cause I'm an idiot).

I've tried creating logs and log files but they don't show up on the server like I'd expect.  Not being able to debug the code / interaction has been a giant PIA.

Comment: Try giving them a path like `/tmp/mylog.txt` or somesuch

Comment: No dice.  I tried putting the file in the same folder and in the tmp folder.  Changed the permissions to 777 and still nothing.  

I did realize that I was never actually calling the VerifyIPN() function.  I added this code but nothing ever gets written.

$verified = verifyIPN();
if ($verified) {

     file_put_contents('/tmp/postdata.txt', "verified");
}
file_put_contents('/tmp/postdata.txt', "was this executed?");


I really need to find a way to get some debug data.

Comment: OK, I rolled things back to see if I could simplify things.  I uploaded PaypalIPN.php and example-usage.php from paypal's git here: https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php _____________I then added a file_put_contents() in example-usage.php. I then redirected my sandbox business account to https://mywebsite.com/example-usage.php ______I executed a transaction and no files were written.   Something so simple should not be this hard.  I must be doing something fundamentally incorrect._____Edit. I'm seeing the IPN request are failing with this change.

Comment: Well, this is coming down to certs it seems.   I get the error "error setting certificate verify locations:" if I point to cacert.cer file I downloaded.  However, if I point to /ssl/certs/myautomaticsitegeneratedcerts.crt, I no longer get the error.    I now get "unable to get local issuer certificate". _____always something

Comment: use the cacert.cer you downloaded as CAINFO / CAPATH.  Something you generated isn't going to help at all in connecting to PayPal ; see or search for something like https://thisinterestsme.com/php-curl-ssl-certificate-error/ for more help

Comment: I swear I did that but once I moved it to another folder that also had certs, the IPN was finally validated.  Now I just have to get my license stuff working.  Standby

Comment: I finally got it working end to end.  The last issue was found in the error logs.  Removing the namespace declaration from the paypal example_usage file resolved the conflict.  Now I need to clean all this up.